# Inheriting from multiple classes which have the same super class - workaround

Tags: swift, swift3

Following situation:

```
class Sprite{ // has to be a class, not a protocol!
    func s(); // can not be changed
}
class Element: Sprite{
    // needs s(); for:
    func e();
}
class Wiggle: Sprite{
    // needs s(); for:
    func w();
}
```

How could I achieve something like:

```
class Button: Wiggle{
    // needs s();
    // needs w();
}
class Cursor: Element, Wiggle{
    // needs s();
    // needs w();
    // needs e();
}
class Pointer: Element{
    // needs w();
    // needs e();
}
```

This is not working since for Cursor Wiggle and Element both inherit from Sprite.

Hence I was thinking about using an extension approach like:

```
class Button:Sprite{
    // needs s();
    // needs w();
}
class Cursor: Element{
    // needs s();
    // needs w();
    // needs e();
}
class Pointer: Element{
    // needs w();
    // needs e();
}

extension Button, Cursor { // or similar to make w() available in Button & Cursor
    // using s() for:
    // func w();
}
```

How can I extend `Button` & `Cursor` in one single step?

Comment: Use [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html).

Comment: As I already mentioned,  Sprite has to be a class, not a protocol, since it is already implemented (not by me).

Comment: Can you rework it?

Comment: no, its something like Apple's SKSpriteNode

Comment: You can add a protocol that implements `w()`, has a default implementation, and is adopted by `Button` and `Cursor`

Comment: but then I would not be able to use s() which is needed for w(), right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116140/discussion-between-amomchilov-and-cocoseis).

Comment: `Sprite` may need to be a class, but `e` and `w` don't. They could be default implementations in protocols, `Elemental` and `Wiggly`, respectively. Then `Wiggle` could conform to `Wiggly`, `Pointer` could conform to `Elemental`, and `Cursor` could conform to both.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your `w()` in its own protocol, e.g. `Wable`, to which `Button` and `Cursor` conform. Give `Wable` a default implementation for `w()`. Because `w()` depends on `s()`, you must impose a constraint on the extension such that only it only applies to conforming types deriving from `Sprite` (the "source" of `s()`).

```
class Button: Sprite, Wable {
    // needs s(); inherited from Sprite
    // needs w(); inherited from Wable
}

class Cursor: Element, Wable {
    // needs s(); inherited from Sprite
    // needs w(); inherited from Wable
    // needs e(); inherited from Element
}

class Pointer: Element, Wable  {
    // needs w(); inherited from Wable
    // needs e(); inherited from Element
}

protocol Wable {
    func W()
}

extension Wable where Self : Sprite {
    func W() {
        print("foo")
    }
}
```

Comment: See [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2)
 - Protocls - Property Requirements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID269)

Comment: of course, but it gives me a `Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable`

Comment: So is your question answered then?